# Run .sql script through a nant build process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, nant

Okay, so I have a .build file that contains targets to execute specific tasks to build a solution. Say I have .sql file in a folder that I want to run. I need to use .build file to run this sql script. How can I create the target?
More precisely, this is what I have and what I need

```
<target name="run.sql.script" description ="will run my script">
<exec program="what goes here??" commandline="-d mydb -S myserverinstance i C:\mysqlscript.sql">
</target>
```

If it matters at all, I want to run the script against sql server 2008 R2

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic question was how would you run this from a command-line?  You probably want to look at `osql.exe` (older) or `sqlcmd.exe` (newer) in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\{version}\Tools\Binn`  See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/05/sql-server-sqlcmd-vs-osql-basic-comparison/ for a comparison.

Run like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx):

`sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql`

Comment: Thanks robrich. That was helpful. Based on my question and your answer I used this command and it works <exec program="sqlcmd.exe" commandline="-d mydb -S myserverinstance i C:\mysqlscript.sql">